# No action was found on the controller 'UpTourism' that matches the request.- MVC4 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a web api in mvc 4. my controller is-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string signIn(string socialId, string email)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TourismModelContainer db = new TourismModelContainer())
            {
                var user = (from log in db.UserDetails
                            where ((log.FacebookId == socialId || log.GoogleId == socialId) && log.IsActive==true)
                            select new { log.Id, log.Mobile, log.Gender, log.Country }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    string json = new Utills().ObjectToJson(user); ;
                    if (email == null || email == "")
                    {
                        return json;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool isEmail = db.UserDetails.Where(o=>o.IsActive==true).Any(obj => obj.Email == email);
                        if (isEmail)
                            return "1";
                        else
                            return json;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

my WebApiConfig.cs file is

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and my route config is -

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

but when i call this sign in service, I get following error-

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58851/api/UpTourism/signIn'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'UpTourism' that matches the request."
>   }

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Make sure that the name of your controller is (UpTourismController)

Comment: Yes Its UpTourismController.

Comment: Please post code of Controller class itself (with single empty action, there is no reason to show wall of code not related to routing), actual calls to RegisterRoutes/Register methods and how you call the method (whatever you use to construct post request).

Comment: I am using postman to make a post request. and my routes and webapi config is mentioned above.

Comment: Not good that your controllers and API routes goes to same path *api*/{controller}/{action}/{id}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

During `HttpPost` you can send only one parameter to action.So clubbing the two parameters you have inside a class and sending that object is much easier and convenient.I created a `Demo` class.And my controller is `CustomController`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *During HttpPost you can send only one parameter to action* - That is not true at all.

Comment: I thought that was a rule of thumb - @Rob

Comment: @Rob: I used to believe like you, but when it comes to the crappy implementation of Web Api 1.0 routing, I'm losing the faith.